# Loading different stylesheet based on your users location

Tags: java, stylesheet, userlocation

I have a small issue.

Im trying to develop a solution with java that will allow me to load a specific stylesheet based on the users location.

I am not that well versed in scripting things myself and typically use jquery plugins.

If you could help me out with a little code to get me started or point me in the direction of some tutorials that would be of immense help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.jquery4u.com/tag/jquery-location-api/ together with http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/javascript .There is a complete example on how to use it. When have the location then it's up to you how you want to add/change styling.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, this should help me out quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually could use a little more help wiht this one.

I created a quick else if statement that i would use to load the stylesheets based on the output of the geolocator.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (geoplugin_countryName() == CA) {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main_css.css" media="screen" />
} 
else if (geoplugin_countryName() == US) {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main_css.css" media="screen" />
} 
else if (geoplugin_countryName() == EU) {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main_css.css" media="screen" />
} 
    </script>
```

If someone could take a look at this code and let me know if the syntax will work that would be awesome, as it stands im not too familiar with java.

Thanks

Comment: I've edit your post and modified it slightly,:
<script type="text/javascript">  
if (geoplugin_countryName() == "CA") {  
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='main_css_ca.css' media='screen' />");  
}   
else if (geoplugin_countryName() == "US") {  
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='main_css_us.css' media='screen' /> "); 
}   
else if (geoplugin_countryName() == "EU") {  
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='main_css_eu.css' media='screen' /> "); 
}   
</script>